# Get list of Apps in Android work Profile

Tags: android, android-managed-profile

I need to get the List of apps that are enabled in the Android work Profile/Managed Profile, where My app is the Profile Owner  app or alternatively how to check whether the app with  given package name is Installed in work Profile/Managed Profile.

Comment: did you manage to get it?

Comment: @MihodiLushan see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Most adb commands provide a `--user` option.

Get the user with `adb shell pm list users`

This should output something like:

```
 Users:     
    UserInfo{0:Owner:13} running
    UserInfo{10:<work profile name>:30} running
```

In this case the work profile user id is 10.

Now you can get the packages for that work profile with `adb shell pm list packages --user 10`

https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#shellcommands

Comment: can it be checked programatically while running the app? I don't get it how to run shell commands programmatically in app lifecycle.